# Fluent NHibernate list<T> inside class

Tags: c#, orm, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

I am trying to get a `List<User>` which in turn contains a `List<Article>` for every `User`, however when querying i get the `List<User>` and every `User` (the only `User`) has a `List<Article>` but it doesn't contain anything.

I've checked my DB and the keys match, so my guess (well ,not much of a guess) is that there is some issue in my mapping. I've searched for examples for one-to-many (HasMany) and tried them but nothing's working. Anyone who have any idea what might be wrong?

Classes

```
    public class User
    {
        public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Password { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Article> Articles { get; set; }

        public User()
        {
            Articles = new List<Article>();
        }
    }

public class Article
{
    public virtual int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Ingress { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public virtual string ArticleText { get; set; }
    public virtual User Author { get; set; }
}
```

These are my mappings

```
    public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
    {
        public UserMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.UserId);
            Map(x => x.Name);
            Map(x => x.Password);
            HasMany(x => x.Articles).KeyColumn("UserId").LazyLoad();
        }
    }


    public class ArticleMap : ClassMap<Article>
    {
        public ArticleMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.ArticleId);
            Map(x => x.Title);
            Map(x => x.Ingress);
            Map(x => x.Created);
            References(x => x.Author).Column("UserId").LazyLoad();
            Map(x => x.ArticleText).Length(4001);
        }
    }
```

And here is my call to insert / select

```
        List<User> usr = new List<User>();
        using (var session = SessionFactoryHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {



               User u = new User
               {
                   Name = "Mohindra",
                   Password = "Corn"
               };

               Article a = new Article
               {
                   Title = "Doh!",
                   Ingress = "yada yada",
                   ArticleText = "why dammit! whyyy?!11!!",
                   Created = DateTime.Now,
                   Author = u
               };

               session.Save(u);
               session.Save(a);


               usr = session.Query<User>().ToList();
               transaction.Begin();

               transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
```

This might be the simplest of rookie mistakes but I am very new to using O/RM's so i don't know what might be the issue here.

[image]

Comment: The mappings looks fine so far, but it seems that your user does not contains any articles. `u.Articles.Add(a);` should help.

Comment: Oh, I thought it would be able for FNH to map that "automagically"

Comment: To be honest, I am not quite sure right now. Another reason could be the LazyLoad(). What happens if you iterate over the articles?

Comment: This got pretty embarrassing.. iterate? step through code?

Comment: Well i removed `session.Save(a);` and replaced it with `u.Articles.add(a)`, got this errormessage (object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing or set cascade action for the property to something that would make it autosave. Type: Multimedia.Models.Article, Entity: Multimedia.Models.Article). If I did it with the `session.Save(a)`it added doubles to the DB

Comment: I solved it, I just had to set cascade.All() to my `HasMany(x => x.Articles).Table("Article").KeyColumn("UserId").Cascade.All();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used,
`HasMany(x => x.Articles).Table("Article").KeyColumn("UserId").LazyLoad();`
And then I saved my objects independently.

When I should have used,
`HasMany(x => x.Articles).Table("Article").KeyColumn("UserId").Cascade.All();`

^ In this case the `Article` inherited my `User` and I could then save them with the relation.